# How to set references to CSS and JS in a DotNetNuke skin?

Tags: javascript, css, dotnetnuke

Does anyone know how the precedence works for **CSS** and **JS** references in DotNetNuke?

I understand this precedence can be set via a `Priority` property of the `dnn:DnnJsInclude`  and `dnn:DnnJsInclude`  tags.

It hasn't proved trivial to port an html page with multiple css and js references to a simple skin, where the references to the CSS and JS files are done  by the dnn:DnnJsInclude  and dnn:DnnJsInclude  tags.

I suspect (and hope!) there is a set of values for the priority property that allows the skin to behave **exactly** as the original html page.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to pay attention to the loading order of the default CSS files in DNN, and adjust your priority based on those orders, to control where your files load.

My HammerFlex skin has some good examples of loading order for CSS and Javascript for bootstrap.

https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerFlex/blob/master/Home.ascx

```
<dnn:JQUERY ID="dnnjQuery" runat="server" jQueryHoverIntent="true" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="bootstrapJS" runat="server" FilePath="js/bootstrap.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="10" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="bootStrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="bluImpJS" runat="server" FilePath="js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```